# notepad++ return value from position

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to find and return a value from position with Notepad++?

What i mean is i have a huge txt file and I would like to know the value in position 142-143 in each row.

Example data:

```
2193476219045Y73    4095732904572390458HERG ÖOEJFNTG2P9085GNJERTOGJN0485NFLDN M4508NJWÅOTIGSN4085JN5SEKLGMN40WI5GMN4+5GI4M4+05IGM450GIM3405GM4I0M430I5GM403IN5G4305GN45IGN405IGN450IGBMFDLSBGKD
2193476219045Y73    4095732904572390458HERG ÖOEJFNTG2P9085GNJERTOGJN0485NFLDN M4508NJWÅOTIGSN4085JN5SEKLGMN40WI5GMN4+5GI4M4+05IGM450GIM3405GM7I0M430I5GM403IN5G4305GN45IGN405IGN450IGBMFDLSBGKD
2193476219045Y73    4095732904572390458HERG ÖOEJFNTG2P9085GNJERTOGJN0485NFLDN M4508NJWÅOTIGSN4085JN5SEKLGMN40WI5GMN4+5GI4M4+05IGM450GIM3405GM5I0M430I5GM403IN5G4305GN45IGN405IGN450IGBMFDLSBGKD
2193476219045Y73    4095732904572390458HERG ÖOEJFNTG2P9085GNJERTOGJN0485NFLDN M4508NJWÅOTIGSN4085JN5SEKLGMN40WI5GMN4+5GI4M4+05IGM450GIM3405GM4I0M430I5GM403IN5G4305GN45IGN405IGN450IGBMFDLSBGKD
2193476219045Y73    4095732904572390458HERG ÖOEJFNTG2P9085GNJERTOGJN0485NFLDN M4508NJWÅOTIGSN4085JN5SEKLGMN40WI5GMN4+5GI4M4+05IGM450GIM3405GMKI0M430I5GM403IN5G4305GN45IGN405IGN450IGBMFDLSBGKD
```

Would result as:

```
4
7
5
4
K
```

## EDIT:

**Both answers below from Matt Champion & Kokkie work nicely. Too bad I can't accept both as correct answers :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the find and replace window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> by default, or go to `Search` -> `Replace...`). From here, change the "Search Mode" (lower left of the window) to "Regular expression" and make sure that `. matches newline` is not ticked.

In the `Find what :` field, enter `(.{137})(.{2})(.*)` and in the `Replace with :` field, enter `$2`. This will match the characters that you are looking for (the numbers may seem wrong, but read the explanation below for more details). It may seem like it hasn't matched anything, but make sure to scroll to the left to make sure as my window moved to the right after replacing meaning that I couldn't see any output, but it was just obscured by the left edge of the screen.

## Explanation

`(.{137})` will match the first 137 characters, no matter what they are (numbers, letters, symbols etc.). We need to match these even though we don't want to display them because otherwise they would be left behind when replacing. As a side note, the reason that we use `137` here instead of `141` is because of the fact that (in Notepad++ at least), the tab character technically counts as a single character, even though it moves the text along by 4 lines.

`(.{2})` will match the next two characters, again regardless of what character they are. (You say that you want the two characters at position 142-143, but then give an example of only the character at 143. If you wanted only the second character, change `137` to `138` and change the `2` in this group to `1`.

`(.*)` will match everything else on the line, which is necessary to do only because otherwise you would still see these characters after the replace.

`$2` is used in the replace field because anything that is matched using a set of parentheses is accessible by using the `$` placeholder followed by a number representing which position the matching group is. In this regex, there are 3 matches, meaning that we would have the values `$1`, `$2` and `$3` to work with if needed (although we only require `$2`).

Answer (score 1):

Here you have another regex solution:

```
find:       ^.{142}(.{1}).*$
replace with:   \1
```

explanation:
^.{142} first 142 characters
(.{1}) the character you are interested in
.*$ the rest on the line

[image]